# How to Use Multiple if then

Tags: linux, scripting

How to use multipal if then elif and else, when the script runs it should ask which version you want to down load. the user will enter the required version then the next command will as per the parameter.

```
echo "n Latrest version"

echo "p Previous version N-1"

echo -n "Which version you want to BackUP [n or p]? "

read Ver

if [ $Ver = n ]; then

echo `$n`

if [ $Ver = per ]; then

echo `$p`

echo "Coping BackUP File"

fi

fi
```

Comment: What is the actual question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If [ conditional expression1 ]
then
statement1
statement2
.
elif [ conditional expression2 ]
then
statement3
statement4
.
.
.
else
statement5
fi
```

Comment: expression1 working properly but  expression2 not working

Comment: your question is not clear. http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-if-statement-examples/ look here and use whatever u need.